# How to group multiple values in a key belonging to an object in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, function, group-by, key-value, lodash

I'm trying to replicate the groupBy method in lodash. Here is my code:

```
var array = [1.1,1.3,2.3,2.5,3.1,3.5];
function groupBy (collection, func) {
    var result = {};
    for (var i=0; i<array.length; i++) {
        var property = func(array[i])
        if ((property in result) === property) {
            result[property] = array[i];
        } else {
            result[property] = array[i];
        }
    }
     return result;
}

console.log(groupBy(array, function(n){return Math.floor(n) }));
```

The trouble I'm having is that the value belonging to the key is being replaced using my first if branch, but I'm not sure how to change this branch to make each key list multiple values associated with it. My output is {'1':1.3, '2':2.5, '3':3.5}, but should be {'1':1.1, 1.3... etc.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't store multiple values on a single object property like that, you need some sort of collection data structure like an array.

```
var array = [1.1,1.3,2.3,2.5,3.1,3.5];
function groupBy (collection, func) {
  var i, property, result = {};

  for (i = 0; i < collection.length; i++) {
    property = func(array[i])

    if (!(property in result)) {
      result[property] = [];
    }

    result[property].push(array[i]);
  }

  return result;
}

console.log(groupBy(array, function(n){return Math.floor(n) }));
```

Answer (score 0):

Like this?

```
var array = [1.1,1.3,2.3,2.5,3.1,3.5];
function groupBy (collection, func) {
    var result = {};
    for (var i=0; i<array.length; i++) {
        var property = func(array[i])
        if (!result[property]) result[property]=[];
        result[property].push(array[i]);
    }
     return result;
}

console.log(groupBy(array, function(n){return Math.floor(n) }));
```

Comment: Yes! I didn't realize that the value was actually an array. I added in an else statement to make it work for my code though:

var array = [1.1,1.3,2.3,2.5,3.1,3.5];
function groupBy (collection, func) {
    var result = {};
    for (var i=0; i<array.length; i++) {
        var property = func(array[i])
        if (!result[property]) {
            result[property] = [];
            result[property].push(array[i]);
        } else {
            result[property].push(array[i]);
        }
    }
     return result;
}

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Here's the corrected version of your code:

```
function groupBy (collection, func) {
    var result = {};
    for (var i=0; i<array.length; i++) {
        var property = func(array[i])
        //if ((property in result) === property) {
        if (!(property in result)) {
            result[property] = [array[i]];
        } else {
            //result[property] = array[i];
            result[property].push(array[i]);
        }
    }
     return result;
}
```

And a different implementation using a `Map`.

```js
var numbers = [1.1, 1.3, 2.3, 2.5, 3.1 ,3.5];

var result = groupBy(numbers, Math.floor);

console.log(result); //Map {1 => [1.1, 1.3], 2 => [2.3, 2.5], 3 => [3.1, 3.5]}

function groupBy(arr, getKeyFrom) {
   return arr.reduce(function (groupedItems, item) {
     var key = getKeyFrom(item);

     if (groupedItems.has(key)) groupedItems.get(key).push(item);
     else groupedItems.set(key, [item]);

     return groupedItems;

   }, new Map());
 }
```